# Need help to fix a snippet from my math grid maze solver

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, math, maze

The idea behind the following code is to test if any number between 0 and 13 + any other number equals 13. If one does both numbers should be saved to a different array but on the same index. So i should have all possible combinations to reach 13 in 2 arrays. But when i run my code I only get 2 combinations which are 0+13 and 13+0. Here is the code:

```js
var number1 = [];
var number2 = [];
var index = 0;
var i = 0;
var j = 0;

//Tests if i + j (from the loop) add up to 13
var test = function(i, j) {
  if (i + j === 13) {
    number1[index] = i;
    number2[index] = j;
    index =+ 1;
  }
}

//1st loop generates i from 0 to 13 in 0.5 step.
for (i = 0; i < 13.5; i += 0.5) {

  //same for j, this number should test with i every loop
  for (j = 0; j < 13.5; j += 0.5) {
    test(i, j);
  }
}

//outputs the 2 arrays, the matching numbers should be stored in
for (i = 0; i < number1.length; i++) {
  console.log(number1[i]);
  console.log(number2[i]);
}
```

Comment: Unrelated, but you don't need to iterate `j` because `j = 13 - i`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `index =+ 1` to `index += 1`

Then `index =+ 1` sets the `index` to 1 it does not increment it by 1 (*as you want*)

---

See [Expressions and operators: Assignment operators <sup>MDN</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Assignment_operators)

Comment: Thank you very much. I was looking at my code for so long and didn't notice anything. Kinda mad it was just such a small thing, but I'm happy it's finally fixed xD I created an Account on Stackoverflow just to fix that code :)